# I'm trying to connect from windows to Samba Shared folder on linux using php

Tags: php, linux, windows, samba

I have php on Windows 7 and I'm trying to connect to Samba Shared folder on Linux but no success.

I'm using this code:

```
// Map the drive
system('net use Y: "\\\\linuxIPaddress\Shared_folder password /user:username /persistent:no>nul 2>&1');
// Open the directory
$dir = "Y:/TMP";
if (is_dir($dir)) {
if (opendir($dir)) {
    print "able to access directory tree.";
}
} else {
print "not access tree.";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found solution for connection using this code

```
$sharename = '\\\\LinuxIPAddress\Shared_folder';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$letter = 'Z:';    

if (!is_dir($letter . "/TMP")) {
    $WshNetwork = new COM("WScript.Network");
    $WshNetwork->MapNetworkDrive($letter, $sharename, FALSE, $username, $password);
}
```

and is working perfect

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to comment yet, so:
@DanielMiovski 's solution did work for me as well. Once I mapped it in the script I was able to manipulate the files I wanted to. However, I ran into a problem. On Windows 10, once the script ended the drive was not deleted from my network drives. I could not manually disconnect it via explorer nor the command prompt because: "The network connection does not exist." I searched for many solutions to this on the internet and finally got it to go away, but it took way to much effort for something that simple. I still wanted to use this code in my script, because it was the only smb solution for php that actually worked for me. I found a solution to both problem. Use @Daniel Miovski 's script above, but at the end, add this line:

```
system('net use Z: /delete /y');
```

This deletes the network drive as soon as the script is done manipulating it. I have not had any troubles of this kind since.

Just thought that I would post this in case anyone else was running into this same problem.